# what is the difference between x:DataType and BindingContext

Tags: xamarin

I have these values on a xamarin.Form page. Both of them give me intellisense. What would be the scenarios to use either or both of them?

```
<ContentPage x:DataType="vm:AboutViewModel" >
 <ContentPage.BindingContext>
    <vm:AboutViewModel>
    </vm:AboutViewModel>
 </ContentPage.BindingContext>
</ContentPage>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`BindingContext` assigns an instance of the specified class at runtime.

`x:DataContext` is a **design time** helper that tells Intellisense what the type of the context for a given block of XAML is